# How to show only Registration form in Fancybox In cakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I am new to cakephp can anyone help me. I have a header.ctp

```
<div id="header">
        <a href="#"><?php echo $this->Html->image('1370972247-tp_logo_ww_1.png', array('alt'=>'wrangler','width'=>'205','height'=>'62','class'=>'logo','title'=>'wrangler','border'=>'0'));?></a>
        <!--Login Background Starts -->
        <div id="login-bg">
            <!--Login Area Starts -->
            <div id="login-area">
                <form action="" method="post" name="Login" id="Login">
                    <label>Members Login:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
                    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" />
                    <?php echo $this->Form->submit('/img/login-btn.gif',
                                                array('div' => false, 'class' => 'login-btn', 'name' => 'submit')); ?>
                    <br class="spacer" />
                </form>
                            <?php echo $this->Html->link('Request Access', 
                                    array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'add'),array('id'=>'linkFancyBox','style'=>'color:#FCF7CC;')); ?>

            </div>
            <!--Login Area Ends -->
        </div>


<!--Login Background Ends -->
        <br class="spacer" />
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#linkFancyBox").fancybox({
'width'           : 600,

        'height'              : 650,

        'overlayOpacity'     :  '0.4',

        'overlayColor'       :  '#000',
    'hideOnContentClick' :   false,

        'autoScale'          :   false,

        'transitionIn'       :   'elastic',

        'transitionOut'  :   'elastic',

        'type'           :   'iframe',
      'scrolling' : 'no'

});
});
</script>
```

when ever i click on Request access link i want to display only form ratherthan whole site please anyone helpme

Answer (score 0):

Yup guys finally got answer for my question .
Step1: Create layout for popup display in app/View/Layouts/popup.ctp for example
step2: Next add only fetch('content'); ?> in popup.ctp
step3: Than call this layout for registration form action in your controller
step4: Than click on link i got the popup with only form ratherthan complete site

Note: Before Step 1,2,3,4 we have to download jquery and css files of fancy box and place it in necessary folders and add it in our main layout file.

```
 Thank you
```